# Get total count of matching documents and count within that subset that satisfies certain criteria

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Say I have the following 5 documents in a collection:

```
{"account_id": 11, "event": ISODate("2021-05-03T10:33:18.220Z")},
{"account_id": 11, "event": ISODate("2021-05-03T10:33:19.220Z")},
{"account_id": 11, "event": null},
{"account_id": 99, "event": ISODate("2021-05-03T10:33:20.220Z")},
{"account_id": 99, "event": null}
```

In a single `aggregate` query I'd like to retrieve:

1. Total number of documents with `acccount_id: 11` (3)
2. Total number of documents with `acccount_id: 11` AND `event` being not null (2)

Essentially, what I'm looking for as a result is this:

```
{ total: 3, with_event: 2 }
```

Below is the code I have that satisfies the second point from the above. It matches account_id and `event` type of 9 which is date time in Mongo. How do I extend this code to also satisfy point 1?

```
mongo.accounts.aggregate([
    {
        "$match": {
            "account_id": 11,
            "event": {
                "$type": 9
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": null,
            "count": {
                "$sum": 1
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$facet` operator to separate both conditions and result,

- `$match` condition for `account_id`
- `total`, `$group` by null and count total document
- `with_event` match for event and `$group` by null and count total document
- `$project` to show required fields, get first element from facet result

```
mongo.accounts.aggregate([
  { $match: { account_id: 11 } },
  {
    $facet: {
      total: [
        {
          $group: {
            _id: null,
            count: { $sum: 1 }
          }
        }
      ],
      with_event: [
        { $match: { event: { $type: 9 } } },
        {
          $group: {
            _id: null,
            count: { $sum: 1 }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      total: { $arrayElemAt: ["$total.count", 0] },
      with_event: { $arrayElemAt: ["$with_event.count", 0] }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/0fsJjDs9vti)

---

**Second approach:**

- `$match` condition for `account_id`
- `$group` by null and get `total` document, and for `event` check condition if type is date then count 1 otherwise 0

```
mongo.accounts.aggregate([
  { $match: { account_id: 11 } },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      total: { $sum: 1 },
      with_event: {
        $sum: {
          $cond: [{ $eq: [{ $type: "$event" }, "date"] }, 1, 0]
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/RUDApFDe_8w)

Comment: Thank you for this. Which one do you think will have better performance?

Comment: i think second one, you can check performance by [explain()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.explain/) state.